# Firefox (cannot save history), PgAdmin4 sqlite issue, Signal, ... may be caused by kernel >5.13 and wrong F2FS file system check

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, sqlite, pgadmin

If you face not working **Firefox** webDeveloperTools or some history issue, or **pgAdmin4** complaining about some weird **sqlite issue** and even Signal messenger doesn't start, then the problem isn't related to FF or pgadmin4 or Signal, but to the way the kernel >5.13.x handels (unclear?) state of F2FS /home partition.

see: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/71611

Answer (score 0):

**instant solution:**
set The sixth field (fs_passno) in /etc/fstab to 2 and reboot.

Example:

```
UUID=<uuid-of-your-device> /home/ f2fs noatime,relatime  0 2 <---change this to 2
```

Jaegeuk Kim / Greg Kroah-Hartman commited already a fix:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.13.4&id=63798e31f5888e322491863f88e9c03c435ce116